# How to fix ''PosixPath' object has no attribute 'encode'" error using librosa.load?

Tags: python-3.x, librosa, pathlib

I'm starting learning basic feature extraction with librosa and was trying reading and storing ten kick drums with pathlib, but it doesn't work since I always getting an encoding error, where as there is no error without pathlib.

I tried changing the path, updating every imported library very often, using wav instead of mp3 but had no further idea.

My code:

```
%matplotlib inline
from pathlib import Path
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, sklearn, urllib, IPython.display as ipd
import librosa, librosa.display
```

```
kick_signals = [
    librosa.load(p)[0] for p in Path().glob('audio/drum_samples/train/kick_*.mp3')
]
```

Error messages:

```
RuntimeError: Error opening 'audio/techno-nine_o_three.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.
```

and

```
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I would be very thankful, if you would and could help me.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the `PossixPath` object to a string, using `p.as_posix()`

Example:

```
p = Path(file_path)
p.as_posix()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
kick_signals = [
    librosa.load(p.absolute())[0] for p in Path().glob('audio/drum_samples/train/kick_*.mp3')
]
```

That way you pass a string instead of a [PosixPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to librosa.

If that does not fix it, check your mp3 file. Does it play in a regular player? If not, please post the whole error message (stacktrace). Perhaps librosa's dependencies aren't installed properly.